R: Extracting values of x from a logistic curve fitted with nls
I'm pretty sure this has a very easy solution but I've been scratching my head at this all day and cannot seem to see where the problem lies.
I am graphing some pharmacological dose-response data (which is working fine), however as an initial step I want convert my somewhat meaningless response variable (output from a plate reader) into readable drug concentrations by extrapolating from a standard curve which I have generated.
The data used for my standard curve is as follows:
structure(list(log_Conc = c(3.45453998496482, 2.85247999363686, 
2.25042000230889, 1.64836001098093, 1.04532297878666, 0.444044795918076, 
-0.161150909262745, -0.763210900590707, -5), Average_log_val = c(0.137454, 
0.1506735, 0.2221405, 0.3992095, 0.846017, 1.5389285, 2.1200975, 
2.3373605, 2.368048)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(
    log_Conc = c(-5, -0.763210900590707, -0.161150909262745, 
    0.444044795918076, 1.04532297878666, 1.64836001098093, 2.25042000230889, 
    2.85247999363686, 3.45453998496482), .rows = structure(list(
        9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .drop = TRUE))

My standard curve is modelled as a 3 parameter logistic which I have coded as such:
standard_curve_logistic <- nlsLM(Average_log_val ~ lower + (upper - lower)/(1 + 10^(log_Conc-midpoint)),
                              data = Standard_cAMP_Curve,
                              start = list(lower = min(Standard_cAMP_Curve$Average_log_val), upper = max(Standard_cAMP_Curve$Average_log_val), midpoint = mean(Standard_cAMP_Curve$log_Conc)))

Plotting the fit of the logistic shows it to model my data nicely
r <- range(Standard_cAMP_Curve$log_Conc)
xNew <- seq(r[1],r[2],length.out = 200)
yNew <- predict(standard_curve_logistic,list(log_Conc = xNew))

plot(Standard_cAMP_Curve$log_Conc,Standard_cAMP_Curve$Average_log_val)
lines(xNew,yNew)


I now wanted to use the standard curve to find a series of x values for given y. Thus I re-arranged the formula of the standard curve, to solve for x. However, doing so returns values which don't seem to be correct at all. I am pretty sure I have re-arranged my formula correctly, so I don't see what's causing the issue here.
params = coef(standard_curve_logistic)

logistic_solve_for_x <- function(upper, lower, midpoint,y_values) { ## Solve algebraic of 3 param logistic for x
  x_value = (log10((upper-lower/y_values-lower) - 1) + midpoint) 
  return(x_value)
}

y_vector <- c(0.5,1,1.5,2) ## Some example values of y to illustrate my point

logistic_solve_for_x(upper = params[2], midpoint = params[3], lower = params[1], y_values = y_vector) 

# The results of this function are: [1] 0.6535569 0.7194098 0.7393143 0.7489347

Reading off the standard curve, you can see these values of x are clearly incorrect (e.g. I'd expect an x of around 0 for a y of 2 etc.)
If anyone can see where I have gone wrong here, I would be so very grateful!

Please provide all non-base R packages in your code. Where does the nlsLM function come from?

A few extra parentheses fixed the formula logistic_solve_for_x <- function(upper, lower, midpoint, y_values) {   x_value = (log10(((upper-lower)/(y_values-lower) - 1)) + midpoint)    return(x_value) } nlsLM is from the minpack.lm package.

Apologies, as @DavoOZ stated, it comes from the minpack.lm package. Also Davos0z your comment has worked for this specific case, so thank you so much!

A few preliminary comments:

nls would have worked here too and it is normally preferable because nlsLM can suffer from premature convergence.  It sometimes appears to work when nls gives an error but usually in those cases there are real problems which ought to be solved and the error in nls alerts us to them.

code to SO should be self contained.  library(minpack.lm) was missing


The code from the question in the Note at the end should be run before running any of the code below.
Here are a couple of alternative approaches.
1) uniroot We can use uniroot to numerically solve the inversion.  f is a function of log_Conc using parameters y and model and returns the difference between the prediction at log_Conc and y. uniroot will solve for the root of that function equal to zero.
We show the solved points in red on the plot below.
f <- function(log_Conc, y, model) predict(model, data.frame(log_Conc)) - y
x_vector <- sapply(
  y_vector, 
  \(y) uniroot(f, r, y = y, model = standard_curve_logistic)[[1]]
)
x_vector
## [1] 1.419654677 0.898921902 0.503686303 0.007363285

plot(Average_log_val ~ log_Conc, Standard_cAMP_Curve)
lines(xNew, yNew)
points(y_vector ~ x_vector, col = "red", pch = 20, cex = 2)

(continued after graph)

2) Ryacas0 We can invert the formula using the yacas computer algebra system via the Ryacas0 package.  Remove the underscores to do that and then it is straight forward to manually create an R function that uses that solution or we can pick apart the yacas output and generate a function. We see that the result is similar to (1) to several decimals.
library(Ryacas0)

s <- "Solve(lower+(upper-lower)/(1+10^(logConc-midpoint))-yvector, logConc)"
yac <- yacas(s); yac
## Yacas vector:
## [1] logConc == midpoint + log(-((upper - lower)/(lower - yvector) + 1))/log(10)

ff <- function(yvector, lower, upper, midpoint) {}
body(ff) <- yac$text[[1:3]]

ff
## function (yvector, lower, upper, midpoint) 
## midpoint + log(-((upper - lower)/(lower - yvector) + 1))/log(10)

ff(y_vector, params[1], params[2], params[3])
## [1] 1.419654165 0.898930737 0.503666159 0.007366106

Note
Run this code from the question before running the code above
library(minpack.lm)

Standard_cAMP_Curve <- 
structure(list(log_Conc = c(3.45453998496482, 2.85247999363686, 
2.25042000230889, 1.64836001098093, 1.04532297878666, 0.444044795918076, 
-0.161150909262745, -0.763210900590707, -5), Average_log_val = c(0.137454, 
0.1506735, 0.2221405, 0.3992095, 0.846017, 1.5389285, 2.1200975, 
2.3373605, 2.368048)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(
    log_Conc = c(-5, -0.763210900590707, -0.161150909262745, 
    0.444044795918076, 1.04532297878666, 1.64836001098093, 2.25042000230889, 
    2.85247999363686, 3.45453998496482), .rows = structure(list(
        9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), ptype = integer(0),
    class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))),
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
row.names = c(NA, -9L), .drop = TRUE))


standard_curve_logistic <- nlsLM(
  Average_log_val ~ lower + (upper - lower)/(1 + 10^(log_Conc-midpoint)),
  data = Standard_cAMP_Curve,
  start = list(lower = min(Standard_cAMP_Curve$Average_log_val),
               upper = max(Standard_cAMP_Curve$Average_log_val), 
               midpoint = mean(Standard_cAMP_Curve$log_Conc)
           )
)
  
r <- range(Standard_cAMP_Curve$log_Conc)
xNew <- seq(r[1], r[2], length.out = 200)
yNew <- predict(standard_curve_logistic, list(log_Conc = xNew))

params = coef(standard_curve_logistic)
y_vector <- c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2)


Apologies for missing out the (minpack.lm) package, and good to know about nls(). Also thank you so much for you anwser, it works perfecctly! I did initially experiment with trying to use uniroot, however I (somewhat stupidly) concluded it would only work on functions with a local minimum/trough (like a polynomial). Could you explain what \(y) and the r parameter do in uniroot(f, r, y = y, model = standard_curve_logistic)[[1]]  Finally, thanks for highlighting Ryacas0 to me, will probably be more handy than pen and paper

\(y) is a short form for function(y) that is commonly used for anonymous functions.  r is the interval within which to find a solution and is defined in the question and also in the Note at the end.

I think the steps to solve for x are just a little off and it should be something like below. Guessing I expect this was something like dividing both sides by (U - L) then subtracting 1 from each side instead of cross multiplying by the denominator, but I don't do a lot of math by hand in my day to day so I could be off.
I'd also mention that sometimes I have ended up using formulas that I don't feel comfortable solving for x in and when that happens I might predict from the model with really dense support then find the closest match to the y value you're looking to solve at in those predictions (see the lazy way below).
logistic_solve_for_x <- function(upper, lower, midpoint,y_values) {
  x_value = log10((upper - y_values)/(y_values - lower)) + midpoint
  return(x_value)
}
y <- seq(params[1], params[2], 0.1)
plot(Standard_cAMP_Curve$log_Conc,Standard_cAMP_Curve$Average_log_val)
lines(xNew,yNew)
lines(x = logistic_solve_for_x(upper = params[2], midpoint = params[3], lower = params[1], y),
      y = y, col = "red") # matches within the values of y

# the lazy, avoiding doing math way
newdf <- data.frame(log_Conc = seq(-5, 5, 0.001))
newdf$pred <- predict(standard_curve_logistic, newdata = newdf)
y_value <- 0.5
newdf[which.min(abs(newdf$pred - y_value)), "log_Conc"] #  1.42
logistic_solve_for_x(upper = params[2], midpoint = params[3], lower = params[1], 0.5) # 1.419654



Although G.Grothendieck's anwser is perhaps more precise, your approach also works perfectly well for my use case, so thank you!
